# Is it possible to prevent users from modifying the code in an HTML plugin?

Tags: html, security, plugins

I want to write an HTML plugin widget for users to include in their own websites. But given the way it works, it would be very easy to "game the system" by modifying the code.

In a nutshell, the widget would include instructions on how to use it, and a few POST links that lead to my site. The system is based on fair play, and it would be easy for somebody to alter the instructions, thereby altering the outcome.

Are there any techniques to prevent people from altering the content of plugins? I envision some way to keep the links from working if the instructions and styling aren't in place.

This is a simplified version of what the plugin might look like:

```
<html>
  Are you satisfied with this website?
  <a href="www.website.com/satisfied/third-party-domain" method=post remote=true>Yes</a>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there's no real way to prevent people from modifying your code.

Most web savvy users that are building with your plugin will eventually pull it apart and make changes. You can certainly add comments in there to ask people to be reasonable and not alter the credits on your plugin, but what you're sort of asking about is DRM in html which is being fought against at present.